# How to add manipulators to an existing menu

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-8

I even don't know how to ask this question. In the below code (I found from an example), along with default manipulators I want to add another manipulator to remove all link outside siblings.

```
$manipulators = array(
  array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
  array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  // This is what i want to do. Remove all links outside of siblings and active trail
  array('callable' => 'mytheme.menu_transformers:removeInactiveTrail'),
);
```

Where to place this 'removeInactiveTrail' method in which class?

Answer (score 4):

It's always hard to ask a right question if you are drupal newbie. However, if you've got that far and found the snippet that serves your task, it's better to do a research in core and contrib modules to find how others use these functions and methods.

If you're not sure of implementation just add more details on what you're trying to achieve.

Here's the example you can use in custom module:

```
function mymodule_render_menu($menu_name) {
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  // Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
  $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
  // Load the tree based on this set of parameters.
  $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

  // Transform the tree using the manipulators you want.
  $manipulators = [
    // Add your manipulators here
  ];

  $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);
  // Finally, build a renderable array from the transformed tree.
  $menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);

  return  array('#markup' => render($menu));
}
```

The above function returns renderable array. You can call it from [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x), add into variables array and output in template.

Again, your task is not clear, edit your question to be more specific.